# load qUnit asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, dependency-injection, qunit

I am trying to load QUnit in js but the addevent function in QUnit.js is never fired, and it's just not working:

```
var appendQUnit = document.createElement('script'); 
appendQUnit.src = 'js/utility/qunit/qunit.js';
appendQUnit.type = 'text/javascript'; 
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(appendQUnit);
```

Comment: Can I ask why you are trying to load qunit like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jquery's [`getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/), example:

```
$.getScript('js/utility/qunit/qunit.js', function() {
    // here you can handle the qunit code
});
```

because the browser will always load javascript files in async mode, you will need some callback to place your code that handles the new loaded js code.

Answer (score 6):

You might need also to call QUnit.load() in order to initialize QUnit:

```
$.getScript('js/utility/qunit/qunit.js', function(){
QUnit.load();
// here you can handle the qunit code
});
```

Comment: +1 `load()` isn't documented in the current version, so I'm not entirely sure how far to trust it, but after several hours of trying everything I can find, this is the only thing that got QUnit and Requirejs playing nicely together for me.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was using `QUnit.init(); QUnit.start();`. I got the tests, but not the userAgent or options.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in your code or as a bookmarklet:

#### Code

```
void(function foo()
  {
  /* get head element */
  var head=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

  /* create script and link elements */
  var qUnitJS = document.createElement("script");
  var qUnitCSS = document.createElement("link");

  /* link rel and type attributes required for lazy loading */
  qUnitCSS.rel="stylesheet";
  qUnitCSS.type="text/css";

  /* define script src attribute to lazy load */
  qUnitJS.src = "http://qunitjs.com/resources/qunit.js";

  /* append script and link elements */
  head.appendChild(qUnitJS);
  head.appendChild(qUnitCSS);

  /* define link href after DOM insertion to lazy load */
  qUnitCSS.href="http://qunitjs.com/resources/qunit.css";

  /* call tests after QUnit loads */
  qUnitJS.onload = function () {};
  }() )
```

#### Bookmarklet

```
javascript:void(function foo(){var head=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; var qUnitJS = document.createElement("script"); var qUnitCSS = document.createElement("link"); qUnitCSS.rel="stylesheet"; qUnitCSS.type="text/css"; qUnitJS.src = "http://qunitjs.com/resources/qunit.js"; head.appendChild(qUnitJS); head.appendChild(qUnitCSS); qUnitCSS.href="http://qunitjs.com/resources/qunit.css"; qUnitJS.onload = function () {};}() )
```

In Firefox, set `security.mixed_content.block_active_content` to false in `about:config` to run the [mixed active content](https://blog.mozilla.org/tanvi/2013/04/10/mixed-content-blocking-enabled-in-firefox-23/) as a bookmarklet.

**References**

- [Don't Docwrite Scripts](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2012/04/10/dont-docwrite-scripts/)
- [Making the HTTP Archive Faster](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2012/04/09/making-the-http-archive-faster/)